# Next.js unexpectedly building home page to /index/index.html instead of /index.html

Tags: next.js, tinacms, tina-cms

I can't seem to figure out why, as the title indicates, I'm ending up with my site's home page at the path `/index/index.html` instead of the root `/index.html` when building with Next.js 14.0.4 using `next build` and `output: "export"` set in `next.config.js`.

I created the site using Tina's `create-tina-app`, which uses [this repository](https://github.com/tinacms/tina-cloud-starter) as a template. The Markdown file which becomes the homepage is at the path (with respect to my project folder) `content/pages/index.md`, and there is also a file `pages/[filename].tsx` which from my understanding handles all pages (i.e. all files in `content/pages/*`).

I've tried renaming the file now located at `content/pages/index.md` (it was originally `content/pages/home.md`), but it seemed that changing that made no difference. Also, strangely, there is another page at `content/pages/in-the-media.md`, and upon running `next build` it builds to `/in-the-media.html` — no subdirectory, as expected.

The `tina-cloud-starter` template I used also defines these rewrites in `next.config.js` by default:

```js
async rewrites() {
    return [
      {
        source: "/",
        destination: "/home",
      },
      {
        source: "/admin",
        destination: "/admin/index.html",
      },
    ];
  },
```

However, as an error message notes when running `next build`, [rewrites are not supported using `output: 'export'`](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/building-your-application/deploying/static-exports#unsupported-features). Hence, I removed it from my project's `next.config.js`. I think this is probably the crux of the issue, but I don't see why a rewrite should be necessary to begin with.

If this isn't already obvious, I'm pretty new to Next.js (and even JavaScript as a whole; I've done more Ruby and Python), so I apologize if this is something obvious I'm missing. I think this is my first proper StackOverflow question, too; if I should change anything or if any additional information would help, just let me know!

Thank you so much!